# Insertar imagen en json

Tags: json, imagen

Muy buenas, estoy recorriendo un json en php y depende de el valor de uno de los campos, me gustaría concatenarle una imagina al campo, si le pongo un texto funciona bien pero al hacerlo de esta forma con una imagen no.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

```
foreach ($obj as $data) 
    {  
        if ($data->estado_col == '1')
        {
        $data->name= <img src='bombillaV.png' > .($data->name); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEFINICIÓN DE JSON**

> `JSON`, acrónimo de **JavaScript Object Notation**, es un formato de
>   texto ligero para el intercambio de datos.

Como la definición lo dice **es un formato de texto** por lo cual no puedes agregar en el etiquetas html, lo que puedes hacer es agregar simplemente el nombre de la imagen y en el momento en que desees imprimir llamas la propiedad en la cual guardaste ese nombre y listo.

Esto podrías hacer para guardar:

```
foreach ($obj as $data) 
{  
    if ($data->estado_col == '1')
    {
    $data->imagen = 'bombillaV.png';
    }
}
```

Y esto para imprimir:

```
foreach ($obj as $data) 
    {  
        if ($data->estado_col == '1')
        {
        echo '<img src="imagenes/'. $data->imagen .'">'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, el problema es que no tengo un campo imagen, la imagen la tengo en una carpeta y mi intención era concatenarla junto a un campo de texto en esta caso name. No hay forma de hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Puedes concatenar solo el nombre y separarlo con algún caracter como por ejm # y al momento de imprimir hacer un split para que el nombre de la imagen y el nombre del dato queden separados